# adding value together with the existing value in database

Tags: .net

I am developing an application and I want it update some information and to add the value of quantity in the existing database to the new value enter by the user.  It's updating properly but instead of adding quantity together it's putting the new value at d back of existing value in database e.g if I have 5 in the database before and 3 in the new textbox instead of the new value to be 8, it's showing 35 in database.  This is my code,  how can it be adding the value 
            con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\pharmacy.mdb")
            con.Open()
            Dim ct1 As String = "select * from stock where code= '" & TxtCode.Text & "'"

```
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct1)
        cmd.Connection = con
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If rdr.Read Then

            con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\pharmacy.mdb")
            con.Open()

            Dim cb As String = "UPDATE stock SET company = @d1 , Productname =@d2, code=@d3, quantity= [quantity] + @d4, unitPrice = @d5, ddate = @d6, batchNo = @d7, Type = @d8, expDate =@d9 " + "WHERE code = @d3"

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)

            cmd.Connection = con


            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d1", "company"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d2", "productName"))


            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d3", "code"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d4", "quantity"))

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d5", "unitPrice"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d6", "ddate"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d7", "batchNo"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d8", "type"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d9", "expDate"))



            cmd.Parameters("@d1").Value = CmbCompany.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@d2").Value = TxtPrdtName.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d3").Value = TxtCode.Text


            cmd.Parameters("@d4").Value = TxtQuantity.Text

            cmd.Parameters("@d5").Value = (TxtunitPrice.Text)
            cmd.Parameters("@d6").Value = TxtDate.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@d7").Value = TxtBatchNo.Text()
            cmd.Parameters("@d8").Value = CmbType.Text
            cmd.Parameters("@d9").Value = dtpExpirationDate.Text


            cmd.ExecuteReader()

            MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated", "Product Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            rdr.Close()
            con.Close()
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it's displaying message,  undefined function 'convert'  in expression.  What should I do

Comment: What is the stock column defined as? I bet it's not any type of number....